# how to call the array fields inside JSON from node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request

In node.js app, In server.js file I am trying to the request and the print the values to console from an external api called Deckofcardsapi using the below code.

```
const  request = require('request');
request('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count=2', function (error, response, body) {
const data = JSON.parse(body);
console.log('remaining :', data.remaining);
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
console.log('suit:', data.cards[suit]);
});
```

when i try `data.cards[suit]` i get an error as below.

```
console.log('suit:', data.cards[suit]);
ReferenceError: suit is not defined
at Request._callback (/Users/lokanathc/Projects/deckOfCards/server.js:48:37)
at Request.self.callback (/Users/lokanathc/Projects/deckOfCards/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/lokanathc/Projects/deckOfCards/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/lokanathc/Projects/deckOfCards/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)`
```

but when i use just `data.cards` i get the following output

```
remaining : 50
statusCode: 200
suit: [ { code: 'QC',
images:
 { png: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.png',
   svg: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.svg' },
value: 'QUEEN',
image: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.png',
suit: 'CLUBS' },
  { code: '5S',
images:
 { png: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/5S.png',
   svg: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/5S.svg' },
value: '5',
image: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/5S.png',
suit: 'SPADES' } ]
```

What should i use to access the value of `suit: 'SPADES'`.

This is the below response from the API .

```
{
"success": true,
"cards": [
    {
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KH.png",
        "value": "KING",
        "suit": "HEARTS",
        "code": "KH"
    },
    {
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/8C.png",
        "value": "8",
        "suit": "CLUBS",
        "code": "8C"
    }
],
"deck_id":"3p40paa87x90",
"remaining": 50
}
```

Comment: The error is right, `suits` is not defined, what is defined however, is `data.cards["suit"]` or  `data.cards.suit`

Comment: I tried that, I am getting output as 
`remaining : 50
statusCode: 200
suit: undefined`

Comment: you are looking for a key. in your example you arent putting the key in "" have you tryed adding these quotes ?

Comment: @JanWillemHuising yes i tried that too. Is there any other way i can do this. should i create an array and then push the value and then access it ?

Comment: I suggest that you take some time to learn JavaScript's object syntax and to learn how it is different from JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use filter method, example:

`data.cards.filter(card => card.suit == 'SPADES');`

[Documentation of filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter%20Documentation%20of%20filter%20method)

EDITED:

If you want to access to all values of `suit` in a array of objects:

`let suites = data.cards.map(card => card.suit); // suites is ['SPADES','HEARTS']`

Comment: This works in the case, where i would need only array of values, where suit = 'SPADES', but i need the value of suit, it can be anything.

Comment: Yes, this works better, can you explain me the use of map, incase i have to combine both, 'value' with 'suit' , like '10' of 'CLUBS'.

Comment: In this case, filter method is the best solution: 
`data.cards.filter(card => card.suit == 'CLUBS' && card.value == '10');`. You should read the documentation of array and its methods [Array's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

To access the suit value which is inside the cards array, we need to access the array first with it index and then the name of required field name which is residing in the array.
This worked for me.

```
console.log('suit:', data.cards[0].suit);
```

So for the below code,

```
const  request = require('request');
request('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count=1', function (error, response, body) {
const data = JSON.parse(body);
console.log('remaining :', data.remaining); 
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
console.log('suit:', data.cards[0].suit);
});
```

The output is:

```
remaining : 51
statusCode: 200
suit: HEARTS
```

This output is for count=1, if we are using count = >1, then we need to iterate the array using for loop.